# Easiest Way To Fetch Data

Tags: php, sql

So maybe someone can help me wrap my head around an appropriate SQL statement to get the desired results I want.

So, I'm calling a table called "invoices" from the db with "SELECT * FROM invoices" sql statement. (I'm using the wildcard because I'm pulling all data and it is about 8 rows.)

I've added a feature to this project where there are 3 different account types. "Marketing, IT, and Security" This is reflected in a column in the "Accounts" table.

So the accounts table will have 2 columns we will need to understand to complete the desired task.

We have "Account ID" that acts as the primary key, and "Department" that acts as the account type.

The invoice has a "Associated Account" column that is the "Account ID" value to the account the particular invoice belongs in.

Let's say, I want to show all invoices for the "Marketing" department. Is there an SQL statement I can use to accomplish this or do I need to structure it a different way.

I don't really fully understand JOIN and UNION queries so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: I wish I'd get a reason for a downvote so I could structure my future questions better or otherwise make improvements on my posts. I'm not sure why this instantly gathered 2 downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select * from Invoices where  AccountId,Account_Name in (Select AccountId,Account_Name from Accounts where Account_Name ='Marketing');` This means all the data of invoice for all those accounts which are Marketing and exists in accounts table. And, The join is for joining two related tables (mostly not a compulsion though) plus for union it works when both the tables have same no of columns and type as well.

Comment: if you think this is the correct answer you wanted can you mark it as correct ans?

Comment: I had actually accepted an answer. That is the first solution I tried and it worked. I'm curious to learn the difference between the two proposed methods (yours and the accepted answer). Is one quicker than the other?

Comment: Joining the tables is better when there are more columns and especially if data is more see as in this case i used subquery because i had max of 2 columns accid and name with in clause meaning itll give multiple accounts to check with. It is like i am taking a reference to check if answer exists in that book if yes give me the corresponding details but if in case data was large and columns related were more then we had to join as we cant write more columns like select c1,c2,c3..n in table in other case

Comment: Right on. Makes perfect sense. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select a.Department,i.InvoiceID from #Accounts AS a
INNER JOIN #Invoice AS i    ON  a.AccountID = i.AssociatedAccountID
WHERE a.Department = 'Marketing'
```

Please modify table names and column names as needed.

In your case, if you apply `INNER JOIN` to both the tables on `Account ID`, you will only get the `invoices` related to an `Account ID` and you can narrow it to each `Account ID` by using a `WHERE` clause.

`UNION` doesn't apply here. You use `UNION` only when you want to retrieve similar data from both the tables having similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

In a relational database, you often need to join tables together in a meaningful way. Thus the keyword "join". 
Sounds like that is exactly what you want.

It also sounds like you are on a good way, since you seem to have understood the importance of a primary and foreign key, to bind the tables together.

Maybe something like this can do the trick (I suspect you have a foreign key called account_id in the invoice table):

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
INNER JOIN accounts ON invoices.account_id = accounts.account_id
```

I would start by reading something like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it structured will work, but it's not necessarily the best structure by any stretch of the imagination. (I would rename that table to be called "Departments" if that is what it will reflect, etc.)

```
SELECT invoices.*
FROM invoices
    INNER JOIN accounts on invoices.accountID = accounts.accountID
WHERE accounts.Department = 'Marketing'
```

- By stating "invoices.*" you are saying only show me the data from the invoices table.
- By INNER JOIN'ing the two tables on their associated fields, you will be returning only data that exists in both tables (i.e invoices that have any departments created in your accounts table).
- By stating you only want to see "Marketing" in the where clause you will then filter those joined results down to just that criteria.